# Limiting a div height to two lines of text inside it?

Tags: html, css

As the question says how to limit a div's height to one/two/n lines of the text inside it?

Comment: Not understanding. You mean one to two lines above and below the text?

Comment: I want to proportion a div's height sth like <div style="(n)*font-size">

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
div {
    height: 1em; // that's one line, 2em for 2 lines, etc...
    line-height: 1em; // the height of one text line
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will display a div with a height the size of the current font size, and any overflow is clipped.  As long as line-height and height are equal there will be one line of text.  The proportion of height/line-height determines the number of lines displayed.

Comment: 1em is usually less than `line-height:normal` and causes the lines to appear squished together. The normal line-height value is roughly evaluated to 1.2, depending on the browser and the font-family.

Comment: Also it is recommended to use `line-height: 1;` instead of `line-height: 1em;`. They achieve the same result but using unitless version sidesteps potential inheritance weirdness with `em`.

Answer (score 8):

The `em` unit adjusts by `font-size`, and `line-height` proportions are also based on that. So those are what you want to be using for "fixing" height.

You want either this:

```
div {
    height: 2.2em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpqnW/1/)

Or if you want it to potentially reduce to 1 line, then use this:

```
div {
    max-height: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpqnW/47/)